# What security measurements we should take if we are storing banking details?

Tags: security, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, finance, banking

I am developing a mobile app, a market place buyers and sellers can meet.

When making payments, the buyer will have to enter his credit card information every time, because we are not saving them.

To get paid, sellers need to have their bank details stored with us (That's what we think). We are planning to use a payment gateway like `Stripe` or `Braintree`.

Now, we have 2 questions.

1. Instead of we storing the bank details, can we shift this responsibility to the payment gateway provider? So the information are with that service and not with us.
2. If it is mandatory for us to keep the bank details, what security measures we need to take?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Braintree, but Stripe can handle storing those.  I'd suggest reaching out to them to tell them more about your use case and ask for more details.  https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks. That means they will take care of these data right? Anyway in case of recurrent payment, I know they will keep them. So I guess the same situation will be applied here.

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  You can collect the details safely - and without them hitting your server - like this: https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=bank_account